# Display CLI program on HDMI connected monitor while connected via SSH

Tags: ssh

I'm have a monitor connected to my Pi via HDMI. There is no GUI OS installed, only the command line. I don't have a keyboard, so I'm SSHing into my Pi.

I have a python script that displays some text. I want to, from my SSH session, cause that python script to display its text on my HDMI connected monitor, instead of in my SSH console. Hopefully that makes sense.

Any suggestions?

Comment: With bash I use the `DISPLAY` environment variable to select the output. I don't know how to do it within a python script. Have look to define or redirect the output channel instead of default stdout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured out. Just have to write to `/dev/tty1`.

In python:

```
f = open('/dev/tty1', 'w')
# write to stream you just opened
```

This only works for linux btw.